# Can't build file_picker in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I want to use file_picker for my project, but I can't manage to find how.
I either won't work for some version, or juste won't built for the more recents one.

With the version 4.1.3, compiling is ok but the plugin doesn't work on my phone (it's ok on chrome emulator thought), the file selection never opens.

I did not forget to add the permission in the manifest. Here is why I have :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myproject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I saw that it was due to Android 13 and that permission was not managed the same way, something like that, and that you had to change to 5.1.0 at least because it was fixed, but I can't build with this version.

Here is my log

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\capu7\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\file_picker-5.3.1\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':file_picker'.
> No signature of method: build_5yvh2q8vvph11jde279dnwzfi.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_5yvh2q8vvph11jde279dnwzfi$_run_closure2) values: [build_5yvh2q8vvph11jde279dnwzfi$_run_closure2@72dec9d1]
```

I tried to change the sdk version, but honnestly I'm super lost and really don't know what to do. I tried many thing that I saw, but I don't really understand everything and couldn't find my exact situtation.

Thank you in advance for you help, and sorry if my post sucks, it's my first one :(

Comment: I am having a same problem right now, 
did you manage to fix it?